# Bad Perf with Sliding Windows in Flink

Tags: scala, apache-flink, flink-streaming

I use this code to perform  my test ([Flink Quick Start](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-release-1.3/quickstart/setup_quickstart.html)):

```
 val text = env.socketTextStream("localhost", port, '\n')

    // parse the data, group it, window it, and aggregate the counts
    val windowCounts = text
        .flatMap { w => w.split("\\s") }
        .map { w => WordWithCount(w, 1) }
        .keyBy("word")
        .timeWindow(Time.minute(15))
        .sum("count")
```

With this Code I have more than 65 000 input / seconde

If I change

```
timeWindow(Time.minute(15))
```

By

```
timeWindow(Time.minutes(15), Time.seconds(1))
```

I have less than 2 500 input / seconde

Is there any way to have better Performance with Sliding Windows ?

Answer (score 4):

With a 15-minute tumbling window, each incoming event is assigned to a single window, whereas with a 15-minute sliding window with a one second slide, each incoming event is copied into 15 * 60 = 900 windows. This obviously has a performance impact.

Depending on your application requirements, you might be able to compute what you need with less overhead by using ProcessFunction, or by implementing custom window logic. For example, you could pre-aggregate into 900 one second windows, and then have a second layer of windowing that incrementally adjusts the 15-minute results by subtracting the expiring second's contribution to the total and adds in the most recent second's worth.